# No plan available - HecRAS

Tags: export, hec-ras

I did an unsteady flow analysis with HecRAS 5.0.7. and want to export my results as GIS - Data. But if I want to select my profile, I got always the same error message

> The plan must be executed for profiles to be available

How can I avoid this error?

Comment: There are many things to be set before you are able to export results to gis format. Which steps have you gone through already? What kind of model do you have 1D or 2D? is that error under the RAS Mapper?

Comment: I build a combined 1D/2D model and did a unsteady flow analysis. I read the manuel and did the same steps. 
I tried it again and checked "post processing" in the  unteady flow analysis. Now I can export my  results as GIS format

Comment: NIce! you copuld post as an answer how you solved it, the mistakes you amend and acept your own aanswer. It will help yourself and others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it again and checked "post processing" in the "Unteady flow analysis" window. Now I can export my results as GIS format.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure that you run the programs that compute the hydraulic info, there are different options available under the Unsteady Flow Analysis, please make sure the Post Processor option is checked. 
You can get more info about Unsteady Flow Analysis here : https://knowledge.civilgeo.com/